# How to add an existing Excel userform & VBA to new spreadsheet (For Dummies)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have an end user who exports data from an accounting program and each time they export and create a new spreadsheet, they need to add a userform and VBA file. Below are the instructions I have provided the end user, but it's cumbersome for an end user.

Can you recommend simpler instructions or a way to add the files more efficiently each time they do a new export?

> You will only have to preform the following steps once after creating a new spreadsheet.
>
> Step 1: Open your exported spreadsheet
>   Step 2: Open the **Visual Basic Editor** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
>   Step 3: Open **Import Macro** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
>   Step 4: Browse to "`Module1.bas`" and open it
>   Step 5: Open **Import Macro** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
>   Step 6: Browse to "`UserForm1.frm`" and open it
>   Step 7: Run Macro (<kbd>F5</kbd>)
>   Step 8: Click **Run**
>
> The Macro is now installed and usable. Click on the **X** to close the dialog box then save your spreadsheet.   From that point forward when you open the spreadsheet all you need to do is click (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) to open the selection form.

Comment: They could [save the macro to their `Personal.xlsb` file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing extraordinary happens here, look Import & Export are simpler methods to Copy File, Module or anything from one File to other or even to other Drive.

If I describe your case, the shown procedure helps to Copy the Macro from that file to yours and nothing.

If you are finding problem to follow the suggested procedure, do the followings.

1. Open that Excel file.
2. Press Alt + F11 to open the VBA Editor.
3. On left side you find the Project Explore.
4. Find the Yellow Folder named Modules, Expand if not.
5. Click the Module, codes will appear to Right Windows Pan.
6. Copy the Codes, open your Excel file, if not open and follow step 1 to 4.
7. Finally Paste the codes in VBA Editor.

To back to the Sheet, Click File then Save then Close & Back to Excel Command. and Run the Macro.

*Hope this help you.*